# .NET cancelling async I/O operations

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, io

In this particular case, I'm writing a TCP/IP server, and I'm using TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient() to accept incoming connections. The server logics is implemented in a single class implementing the IDisposable interface: when Dispose() is called, I want to cancel the BeginAcceptTcpClient() operation.

Now in more general terms: when using the *async I/O model* of .NET (Begin* and End*), how can I cancel the operations?

My idea would be something like this:

```
private volatile bool canceledFlag = false;

this.listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult =>
{
    if(this.canceledFlag) return;

    // ...
}, null);
```

Dispose() would set the flag to true and would also call this.listener.Stop().
However I recall having read that for every Begin* call there must be a matching End* call or bad things would happen.

So how should I do this then? Please note that I'm looking for a **general solution** for cancellation with Begin* and End* methods - I just gave you my concrete usage scenario to help you understand my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *general* solution is to call Close() or Dispose() on whatever object whose BeginXxxx() method you called.  That will cause the callback to run, when you call EndXxxx() then you'll get an ObjectDisposedException.  Which you should catch and treat as a 'end of use' signal, clean up and exit the callback right away.  While frowned upon, the use of an exception for flow control is unavoidable.

For TcpListener, use Server.Dispose(), a bit more efficient than calling Stop().

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much! Could you please elaborate a bit more on Dispose() vs Close() - what is the difference?

Comment: There is no difference, Close() always calls Dispose().  There was some pain and suffering about that in the .NET framework design meetings.

Comment: Sorry, I meant TcpListener.Stop() vs TcpListener.Dispose(). It appears that Dispose() is implemented explicitly, so I assumed that it was because users are meant to use Stop() primarily. So what is difference here?

Comment: @Hans that's a bit backwards, never would have guessed that based on other implementations. Usually dispose calls close.

Comment: @The - well, it isn't very relevant, but take the Stream class for example.  The base class for many derived ones.  Its Close() method calls Dispose().

Comment: @ShdNx - no, TcpListener doesn't have a Dispose() method.  Which is a bit, well, odd.  Some pain and suffering in the System.Net group meetings I imagine.  Their designs are a bit unusual and have gone through a lot of bug revisions.

Comment: @Hans: thanks for the answer! What I'm trying to ask is that you wrote the using Server.Dispose() is more efficient than Stop(). Why is that? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Stop() also disposes the socket but creates a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative I would recommend is not using the async-Begin-End pattern but Tasks.

You can use one of the [TaskFactory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321521.aspx) overloads to create a task from your Begin/End methods and use this. You can use this [.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783219.aspx) overload to specify a continuation with your own CancellationToken to stop it. IMHO it's recommended to use Tasks whenever you can because the next version of C# will build upon Task with it's async/await support.

Here is a nice [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff959203.aspx) explaining the common patterns and Tasks

REMARK:

In my original answer I said you can use .Dispose to kill the Task but this might cause serious problems, because you can only Dispose Tasks in the Completed state.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't thought about that. You certainly have a point. Thank you!

Comment: please take note on my remark - Dispose on a taks can be a problem if it's not finished..

Comment: @CarstenKönig: As far as I understand this doesn't help with the original problem; `FromAsync` creates Task1, `ContinueWith` creates Task2 which is executed after Task1 is completed. Cancelling Task2 does not cancel Task1 or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The AsyncCallback is called when an async process completes. It allows the async thread to rejoin the original, and any exceptions can then bubble up (rather than being lost in the background). It also allows you to capture any return values.

Typically you would use Begin / End pattern as follows:

```
  Action action = () = > DoSomething();
  action.BeginInvoke(action.EndInvoke, null);
```

Or

```
 Action action = () = > DoSomething();
 action.BeginInvoke(OnComplete, null);

 private void OnComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
 {
     AsyncResult result = (AsyncResult)ar;
     var caller = (Action)result.AsyncDelegate;
     caller.EndInvoke();

     // do something else when completed
 }
```

It's up to specific implementations to provide a way to cancel an async process before completion. Usually this is done with a `CancelAsync` implementation that internally stops the task early. In the case of `TcpListener` you can just call `listener.Server.Dispose();`

```
 TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(port);
 IAsyncResult = listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(listener.EndAcceptTcpClient, null);

 // on dispose
 listener.Server.Dispose();
```

Comment: +1 for _It's up to specific implementations to provide a way to cancel an async process before completion._ IMHO that's the only clean way to cancel a asynchronous operation.